# Android refresh class View

Tags: android, class, view, invalidation

I'm using the library [WeekView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/970), I'm trying to refresh the view when click the button but the view is not drawn again.
I call the invalidate() method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elenco_, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
mWeekView = (WeekView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.weekView);
mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);
mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(this);
mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);
mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(this);
--
--
btnAvanti.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            mWeekView.invalidate();

        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not drawn again? Views normally just look the same even if they are drawn again.

Comment: i know. I would not have asked for help

Comment: Is the `calendar` you update even bound to the `WeekView` in any way? A quick glance at the library code seems to suggest you should be calling `mWeekView.goToDate(calendar)`, assuming your goal is to show a specific day on the week view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WeekView` class has a publicly accessible method called: `notifyDatasetChanged();`

If you are looking to change the data displayed then your best bet would be to call that.